# My preload screw doesnt work

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension

The preload screw on my mtb fork is very loose and easy to turn, I have a spring fork. The preload doesn't change even if I loosen or tighten the screw. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: What bike/what fork? Perhaps the adjuster is just cosmetic and doesn't actually change anything inside.

Comment: It's an sr suntour fork. The adjuster used to work perfectly before, but i found it to be unusually loose while doing regular maintenance today.

Comment: It could be broken

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without pictures.

Things to check:

- The spring is broken
- The threads on the preload screw are stripped.

If you take it apart chances are high the issue will present itself.